# Given a yacc grammar, output a program that generates text-file (or graphviz) parse trees?

Tags: utilities

Rather than generating the normal `.tab.c` file, generate some `.tree.c` file, s.t `$ .tree text` outputs the parse tree of the file `text`?

Comment: byacc and bison both have `-g` option to write graphical output for *graphviz*.

Comment: This does not generate the parse tree. This appears to generate a state-machine like thing that represents the parser's operation.